# Oracle SQL query to select records based on condition based on returned value

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query that will return the rows where the validity has ended before the actual end date like the row highlighted in the image

```
condition =  end_date < start_date+validity
```

[image]

Comment: Try this : select count(primarykey) from tablename where  ADD_MONTHS(start_date+validity)>end_date;

Answer (score 0):

The WITH clause in the answer is here just to generate some sample data and, as such, it is not a part of the answer.
I am not sure what is your expected outcome according to your statement (quote) "where the validity has ended before the actual end date" (end quote). I would expect that the validity period starts with START_DATE and lasts for next number of months from VALIDITY column. END_DATE looks like arbitrary entered dates that can be within the validation period or outside.
The STATUS column describes the rows of data.

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
            Select 1 "ID", To_Date('08.08.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "START_DATE", 12 "VALIDITY", To_Date('08.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "END_DATE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 2 "ID", To_Date('08.09.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "START_DATE", 24 "VALIDITY", To_Date('08.09.2024', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "END_DATE" From Dual UNION ALL
            Select 3 "ID", To_Date('08.10.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "START_DATE", 36 "VALIDITY", To_Date('12.10.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "END_DATE" From Dual
        )
SELECT
    ID "ID",
    START_DATE "START_DATE",
    VALIDITY "VALIDITY",
    ADD_MONTHS(START_DATE, VALIDITY) "VALIDITY_END_DATE",
    END_DATE "END_DATE",
  CASE 
      WHEN ADD_MONTHS(START_DATE, VALIDITY) > END_DATE THEN 'End date BEFORE the end of validity period'
      WHEN ADD_MONTHS(START_DATE, VALIDITY) < END_DATE THEN 'End date AFTER the end of validity period'
      WHEN ADD_MONTHS(START_DATE, VALIDITY) = END_DATE THEN 'End Date == End Of Validity Period'
  END "STATUS"
FROM
    tbl
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--          ID START_DATE   VALIDITY VALIDITY_END_DATE END_DATE  STATUS                                   
--  ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------- --------- ------------------------------------------
--           1 08-AUG-22          12 08-AUG-23         08-AUG-23 End Date == End Of Validity Period         
--           2 08-SEP-22          24 08-SEP-24         08-SEP-24 End Date == End Of Validity Period         
--           3 08-OCT-22          36 08-OCT-25         12-OCT-22 End date BEFORE the end of validity period
```

Anyway, the same logic could be implemented even if I got it wrong - in that case - you just need to adjust CASE expression's conditions. If you don't need the STATUS column it can be excluded and moved to the WHERE clause to filter the data.
Your condition from the question

```sql
 condition =  end_date < start_date+validity
```

is in CASE expression stated as

```sql
CASE
...
  WHEN ADD_MONTHS(START_DATE, VALIDITY) > END_DATE THEN 'End date BEFORE the end of validity period'
...
```

Regards...